# Live Agent Pre-Form PersonAccount

Tags: liveagent

I'm trying to match contacts from the Pre-Form with existing PersonAccount and if no match was found to create them new. However, I don't get it running. See the code below, do you have any ideas?

```
<!-- Map the detail inputs to the Contact fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:AccountRecordType" value="xyz" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:AccountClient" value="750" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:PersonAccount" value="FirstName,contactFirstName;LastName,contactLastName;PersonEmail,contactEmail;Client__c,AccountClient;RecordType,AccountRecordType"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:PersonAccount" value="PersonEmail,true;"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:PersonAccount" value="PersonEmail,true;"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:PersonAccount" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true;PersonEmail,true;Client__c,true;RecordType,true;"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:PersonAccount" value="Account"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:PersonAccount" value="true"/>

    <!-- Create a Case every time -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:caseOrigin" value="Chat"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Case" value="Origin,caseOrigin;Subject,caseSubject;"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Case" value="Origin,true;Subject,true;"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Case" value="Case"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Case" value="true"/>

    <!-- Link the Contact to the Case -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.linkToEntity:PersonAccount" value="Case,AccountId"/>
```